# 'ng build' is giving errors in angular core package for 9 version ɵɵFactoryDef

Tags: angular

Below is the error outcome on 'ng build' command. Please let us know the process, to resovle these issues.

even i tried with 'ng build --prod' as suggested in blogs, but no luck.

Environment:

> ng --version

Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 16.20.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: error

Package                           Version

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      9.1.15
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@schematics/angular               9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.901.15
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Issue:

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:217:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

Please let me know the process to resolve the above type build issues in angular 9

Comment: you angular/cdk looks to be for angular 7 update that to a matching version name probably this version should do `npm i @angular/cdk@9.1.3` but check if there is a better matching version at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cdk?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your packages like this?

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.0",
    "core-js": "2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.901.15",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.15",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.901.15",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "0.901.15",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "9.1.15",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "9.1.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.1.0    ",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.15",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "9.1.15",
    "@schematics/angular": "9.1.15",
    "@schematics/update": "0.901.15",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
    "webpack": "4.42.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Wasif Mustahid - its not working, i have verfied by updating the relevant package versions with you mentioned. No Luck :(